# Crash when converting/type cast from NSDate to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

The below line is crashing:

```
NSString * endDate = (NSString *)[NSDate dateString:date];
```

This line works fine

```
NSLog(@"end date:: %@", [NSDate dateString:date]);
```

This method `"dateString"` always return NSDate format. I can't change this because it's been used through out app...

Now, how to convert from NSDate to NSString, any workaround?

Thanks

Comment: You can't convert an `NSDate` to a `NSString` with only a cast... Either you use a `NSDateFormatter`, or `[yourNSDate description]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSDateformatter to set date formatter first then convert NSdate to NSString

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
 NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[jsonObject    objectForKey:@"END_DATE"]];
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MMM-yyyy";
 Label.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourDate]];
```

Answer (score 1):

> This line works fine

```
NSLog(@"end date:: %@", [NSDate
    dateFromEpochString:IRString([jsonObject objectForKey:@"END_DATE"])
    withFormat:nil]);
```

Because the description method of `NSDate` is overridden that returns you the `NSString` of the date.

However

```
NSString * endDate = (NSString *)[NSDate dateFromEpochString:IRString([jsonObject objectForKey:@"END_DATE"]) withFormat:nil];
```

returns you `NSDate` object and you cann't explicitly covert it to `NSString` object!!!

You should convert the `NSDate` object which is returned by `dateFromEpochString:` method to `NSString` by [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

As the format of the date is not shared with us, you can take help from above documentation or check [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsdateformatter).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an [`NSDateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to convert your date to an NSString.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"]; 
NSString *result = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```